# Reusing OAuth request token when user refresh page - Twitter4j on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, twitter

I am using Twitter4J API on GAE/J.

I want to use the request token when user came to my page. (called back URL). And press refresh button. I write following code for that. But When user press refresh button. I got Authentication credentials error. Please see the stacktrance. It works fine when user first time used that token.

**HomeServlet.java** code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(FFConstants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                    FFConstants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            String token = (String) session.getAttribute("token");
            String authorizedToken = (String)session.getAttribute("authorizedToken");

            User user = null;
            if (!token.equals(authorizedToken)){
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                        token, (String) session
                                .getAttribute("tokenSecret"));
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
                user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
                session.setAttribute("authorizedToken", token);
                session.setAttribute("user", user);
            }else{
                user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
            }

            TwitterUser twitterUser = new TwitterUser();
            twitterUser.setFollowersCount(user.getFollowersCount());
            twitterUser.setFriendsCount(user.getFriendsCount());
            twitterUser.setFullName(user.getName());
            twitterUser.setScreenName(user.getScreenName());
            twitterUser.setLocation(user.getLocation());
```

Please suggest how I can do that. I have seen on many website. They retain the user with the same token. Even if user press browser refresh buttion again and again.

Please help.

**Exception stacktrace:**

```
Reason: twitter4j.TwitterException: 401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect. /friends/ids.xml This method requires authentication. 
at twitter4j.http.HttpClient.httpRequest(HttpClient.java:469) 
at twitter4j.http.HttpClient.get(HttpClient.java:412) at twitter4j.Twitter.get(Twitter.java:276) 
at twitter4j.Twitter.get(Twitter.java:228) at twitter4j.Twitter.getFriendsIDs(Twitter.java:1819) 
at com.tff.servlet.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:86) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093) at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360) at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712) at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:238) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139) at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:830) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:235) at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5235) at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5233) at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:24) at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:363) at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$2.run(Server.java:838) at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanRunnable.run(LocalTraceSpanRunnable.java:56) at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanBuilder.internalContinueSpan(LocalTraceSpanBuilder.java:536) at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.startRpc(Server.java:793) at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.processRequest(Server.java:368) at com.google.net.rpc.impl.ServerConnection.messageReceived(ServerConnection.java:448) at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.parseMessages(RpcConnection.java:319) at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.dataReceived(RpcConnection.java:290) at com.google.net.async.Connection.handleReadEvent(Connection.java:466) at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.processNetworkEvents(EventDispatcher.java:759) at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.internalLoop(EventDispatcher.java:205) at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:101) at com.google.net.rpc.RpcService.runUntilServerShutdown(RpcService.java:251) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RpcRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:394) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have identified the issue.

I was using the request token again, if I want to get twitter information of a user. That is wrong. I have to use access token instead. I have written a blog post on it [here](http://www.pakzilla.com/2010/03/01/how-to-use-and-retain-twitter4j-oauth-access-token/).